# Is there a way to have multiple connection to the database with the same context but with different connection strings?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In my current project I have an **ASP .NET Core Web application** and I'm using **Entity Framework with PostgreSQL**.

The connection to the DB is established in **startup.cs** file

```cs
var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DeliveryDb");

services.AddDbContext<DeliveryDbContext>(options =>
           options.UseNpgsql(connectionString, x => x.MigrationsAssembly("DeliveryWebService")));
```

Connection string looks like
`"Host=localhost;Port=5433;Database=delivery-db;Username=postgres;Password=qwerty"`

The problem is that I have different roles, created by `CREATE ROLE ...`, in my database with different rights, etc. My app logic is pretty simple:

- User signs in with his login and password
- This data is transfered to a controller
- Then by this data in Users table I determine the role of this user

And what I want to do afterward is to **close the current connection** to Postgres DB and reconnect to it with a proper user role like a manager or admin, meaning to use different connection strings:

`"Host=localhost;Port=5433;Database=delivery-db;Username=admin;Password=12345"`
`"Host=localhost;Port=5433;Database=delivery-db;Username=manager;Password=67890"`

And this is where I'm stuck. I don't know how to close a connection in EF and then reconnect. I was looking towards `AddDbContextPool` instead of using `AddDbContext` to use a pool of connections to kinda connect to the database with all possible roles. But it didn't work out for me (or maybe I am missing something)...

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you store different connection string ?

Comment: @dotnetstep In appsettings.json

Comment: You only need one connection string.  You are using two different databases on same server so just add a "Use" statement to the query : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/use-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15  So instead of "Select * from table1" try "Use ABC; Select * from table1".

Comment: What do you mean by _This data is transfered to a controller_? do you mean username and password? and Do you get username and password for each time user calls you?

Comment: @MrMoeinM I mean I have an Api controller that gets login and password from the user in its httpget method. Then via repository I access the database, looking for the user in Users table by passed values of login and password. And I end up getting the required user with their role. And now, according to the role, I should choose the connection to the database, wether it would be: "Host=localhost;Port=5433;Database=delivery-db;Username=admin;Password=12345" or "Host=localhost;Port=5433;Database=delivery-db;Username=manager;Password=67890"

Comment: I think you will need at least a child class for the role-based part. You can use DeliveryDbContext to get the user authentication info like this, and you can use a DeliveryRoleBasedDbContext, where you can declare a constructor that can be [called with a connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904017/change-sql-server-connection-string-dynamically-inside-an-asp-net-core-applicati).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options.

**Option 1** Create two Different dbContext that inherit from one base dbContext. One for admin and one for users. Get user's role by adminDbContext and put user's role into HttpContext.Items then get userDbContext from serviceProvider.

```
public abstract class AppDBContext<T> : DbContext where T : DbContext
{
    public AppDBContext(DbContextOptions<T> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class AdminDbContext : AppDBContext<AdminDbContext>
{
    public AdminDbContext(DbContextOptions<AdminDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}

public class UserDbContext : AppDBContext<UserDbContext>
{
    public UserDbContext(DbContextOptions<UserDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Your appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Admin": "Host=localhost;Port=5433;Database=delivery-db;Username=admin;Password=12345",
    "Role1": "Host=localhost;Port=5433;Database=delivery-db;Username=role1;Password=role1_password",
    "Role2": "Host=localhost;Port=5433;Database=delivery-db;Username=role2;Password=role2_password",
    "DefaultRole": "Host=localhost;Port=5433;Database=delivery-db;Username=defaultRole;Password=default_role_password;"
  }
}
```

Your Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    //Need for get IHttpContextAccessor
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    services.AddDbContext<AdminDbContext>(
        option => option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Admin"))
    );

    services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>((services, optionsBuilder) =>
    {
        var httpContextAccessor = services.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();

        var hasRole = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue("Role", out object role);

        string connectionStringName = "DefaultRole";
        if (hasRole)
            connectionStringName = role.ToString();

        var connStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionStringName);
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connStr);
    });
}
```

Your Controller

```
private readonly AdminDbContext adminDbContext;
private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

public HomeController(AdminDbContext adminDbContext, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    this.adminDbContext = adminDbContext;
    this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
}

public IActionResult SomeApi(Model model)
{
    var user = adminDbContext.User.FirstOrDefault(...); // Get user
    var userRole = user.RoleName; // Get user's role
    HttpContext.Items.Add("Role", userRole); // Put user's role in items and we get it's value in startup.cs when we creating UserDbContext's Options

    var userDbContext = serviceProvider.GetService<UserDbContext>();
    //Now you have userDbContext
    ...
}
```

**Option 2** Create custom authentication scheme. This way you authenticate user and detect user's role in authentication process and you don't need to inject ServiceProvider to your service/controller. For more infomation you can read this https://joonasw.net/view/creating-auth-scheme-in-aspnet-core-2

Like option 1 create two dbContexts and appsettings.json.
Create these classes

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class CustomAuthOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
{
    public const string DefaultScheme = "CustomDetectRole";
}

public static class CustomAuthenticationBuilderExtensions
{
    // Custom authentication extension method
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddCustomAuth(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<CustomAuthOptions> configureOptions)
    {
        // Add custom authentication scheme with custom options and custom handler
        return builder.AddScheme<CustomAuthOptions, CustomAuthHandler>(CustomAuthOptions.DefaultScheme, configureOptions);
    }
}

public class CustomAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<CustomAuthOptions>
{
    private readonly AdminDbContext adminDbContext;

    public CustomAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<CustomAuthOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock, AdminDbContext adminDbContext)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
        this.adminDbContext = adminDbContext;
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        //You can use Request object here if you need
        var user = await adminDbContext.User.FirstOrDefaultAsync(...); // Get user
        var userRole = user.RoleName; // Get user's role here

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userRole))
            return await NeedLoginAgain();
        else
            return await Success(userRole);
    }

    private Task<AuthenticateResult> Success(string role)
    {
        var claims = new ClaimsIdentity(CustomAuthOptions.DefaultScheme);
        claims.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        _ = claims.IsAuthenticated;
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(claims), CustomAuthOptions.DefaultScheme);
        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
    }

    private Task<AuthenticateResult> NeedLoginAgain()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.NoResult());
    }
}
```

Your Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    services.AddAuthentication(CustomAuthOptions.DefaultScheme)
    .AddCustomAuth(options => { });

    services.AddDbContext<AdminDbContext>(
        option => option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Admin"))
    );

    services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>((services, optionsBuilder) =>
    {
        var httpContextAccessor = services.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        var role = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Type.Equals(ClaimTypes.Role))?.Value;

        string connectionStringName = "DefaultUser";
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(role) == false)
            connectionStringName = role.ToString();

        var connStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionStringName);
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connStr);
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    ...
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        ...
    });
}
```

and finally your controller

```
private readonly UserDbContext userDbContext;

public HomeController(UserDbContext userDbContext)
{
    this.userDbContext = userDbContext;
}

[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CustomAuthOptions.DefaultScheme)]
public IActionResult SomeApi()
{
    //use userDbContext here
    ...
}
```